# How to prove $\Bigg|{\sum^{\infty}_{n=m}a_n}\Bigg|\leq \sum^{\infty}_{n=m}|a_n|$

Tags: real-analysis

How to prove $$\Bigg|{\sum^{\infty}_{n=m}a_n}\Bigg|\leq \sum^{\infty}_{n=m}|a_n|$$
Where $\sum^{\infty}_{n=m}a_n$ is absolutely convergent.
I can prove this for finite series.

Comment: It's true for any partial sum, hence it must be true for the limit.

Comment: For understanding this, you can see that $|a_n|$ is always positive thus the sum on the RHS sums only positive terms, whereas the LHS sum doesn't.

Comment: I understand the statement. The question is how to prove it rigorously ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By the result for finite series, we have

$$|\sum_{n=m}^{M}a_n| \le \sum_{n=m}^{M}|a_n|\le \sum_{n=m}^{\infty}|a_n| .$$

for all $M.$ So the expression on the left is bounded above by $ \sum_{n=m}^{\infty}|a_n|$ for all $M.$ It follows that the limit as $M\to \infty$ of the expression on the left is bounded above by $ \sum_{n=m}^{\infty}|a_n|.$ In other words

$$|\sum_{n=m}^{\infty}a_n| \le \sum_{n=m}^{\infty}|a_n|.$$

Answer (score 2):

If $A_n\leq B_n$ for every $n,$ and the sequences $(A_n)_n$ and $(B_n)_n$ converge to, respectively, $A$ and $B,$ then $A\leq B.$

This is from the definition of convergence (Definitions are tools to be used!): Take any $r>0.$  There are only finitely many $n$ for which $A_n\leq A-r$ and there are only  finitely many $n$ for which $B_n\geq B+r.$ So for all but a finite collection of values of $n$ we have both $A_n>A-r$ and $B_n<B+r.$

It suffices for this Q that what we have, so far, is that for any $r>0$ there exists some $n$ such that $(A_n>A-r\land B_n<B+r)$ and hence $$B+r>B_n\geq A_n>A-r.$$ This implies $B+r>A-r,$ equivalently $$B-A>-2r.$$ Now this is true for any positive number $r$, so $(-2r)$ can be any negative number. So $B-A$ is greater than any negative number, so $B-A\geq 0.$

In your Q, apply this with  $A_n=|\sum_{j=m}^{m+n}a_j|$ and $B_n=\sum_{j=m}^{m+n}|a_j|.$

Answer (score 0):

As $\sum_{k=1}^\infty|a_k|$ converges, its partial sums as sequence have the Cauchy property. By the finite application of the triangle inequality, as you did, you find that
$$
\left|\sum_{k=n}^\infty a_k-\sum_{k=m}^\infty a_k\right|\le\left|\sum_{k=n}^\infty |a_k|-\sum_{k=m}^\infty|a_k|\right|
$$
so that the Cauchy property also translates to the partial sums of $\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_k$. As $\Bbb R$ is a complete metric space, every Cauchy sequence converges. Now you can commute absolute value and limit on the left side in
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\left|\sum_{k=m}^n a_k\right|\le \lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=m}^n |a_k|=\sum_{k=m}^\infty |a_k|
$$
to get your claim.